# Traversing a tree, but each node visited should visit every node underneath

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am traversing a tree, which is easy and I know how to do this. However, I want to visit each node beneath the current node each iteration. I'm not sure I'm being clear so I will try to illustrate this:

```
        A
      /   \
     B     C
    / \   / \
   D   E F   G
```

1st iteration: Node is A: visits B, C, D, E, F, G
2nd iteration: Node is B: visits D, E
2nd iteration: Node is D: visits F, G

I tried writing this as a normal traversal as so:

```
    public static void addCodes(Message root)
    {
         if (root.getLeftChild() != null){
               root.getLeftChild().setCode(root.getLeftChild().getCode() + "0");
               addCodes(root.getLeftChild());
         }
         if (root.getRightChild() != null) {
               root.getRightChild().setCode(root.getRightChild().getCode() + "1");
               addCodes(root.getRightChild());

         }
    }
```

but this obviously does not work. Each node is visited one time. I understand why, I just don't know how to fix it. If this were iterative, it would be nested loops. What's the recursive equivalent of this?

Comment: Does the order of visiting matter? Will the order 'B,D,E,C,F,G' do as well?

Comment: No, I'm just adding codes based on whether it's in the right or left subtree, it doesn't matter the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
public static void addCodes(Message root)
{
     if (root.getLeftChild() != null){
           root.getLeftChild().setCode(root.getLeftChild().getCode() + "0");
           addCodes(root.getLeftChild());
     }
     if (root.getRightChild() != null) {
           root.getRightChild().setCode(root.getRightChild().getCode() + "1");
           addCodes(root.getRightChild());

     }
}

public static void addCode(Message root)
{
     if (root.getLeftChild() != null){
           addCodes(root.getLeftChild());
           addCode(root.getLeftChild());
     }
     if (root.getRightChild() != null) {
           addCodes(root.getRightChild());
           addCode(root.getRightChild());
     }
}
```

Main calls addCode.